# NodeJS Axios Block CORS

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, cors

I'm trying to configure `axios` running in a NodeJS server app to deliberately block on CORS. As in, I'm trying to test my setup to ensure that CORS have been configured correctly.

The issue I'm facing is that `axios` is ignoring the CORS rule and does the query anyway, regardless of the API server setup. Running the application from the browser blocks on CORS violations correctly, however I need to be able to automate the testing of CORS.

Can someone please let me know how I can tell `axios` to error out on a CORS violation?

```
await axios.post(url, query, {timeout: 1000 * 15})
```

Comment: Axios run from NodeJS isn't subject to the same-origin policy. Only requests originating from the browser have this restriction

Comment: @Phil So it's not possible to tell axios to have the same restriction?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. `axios` doesn't bother doing the 'preflight' `OPTIONS` request when it's not running in a browser. You can replicate the act though and do your own CORS checks by sending your own OPTIONS request.

```
async function testCORS(){
    const url = 'example.com'

    try{
        const result = await axios.options(url, {
            timeout: 1000 * 15,
            headers:{
                origin: 'https://mywebsite.com'
            }
        })
        if(result.status === 204){
            return true;
        }
    } catch(error){
        console.error(error.message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Make sure you set the `origin` header as this is what's used in the check.

A successful CORS check comes back as status 204, while a failure comes back as 404.